# Run a script at specific time intervals

Tags: python

How can I run some code, say every 5 minutes, at exact minutes (seconds=0). 
I know I can get the time with `datetime.datetime.now()` every second and check to see if its minutes is a multiple of 5 and seconds is equal to 0 but isn't there any other way that does not require me to check the time every second?

Comment: Consider using [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: You can also get the current time, then time.sleep() till the next multiple of 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use datetime like you have to get the difference in time (multiply to get seconds) from now to when you want to run the script and then use `time.sleep()` for that number of seconds.

https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-time-sleep-pause-wait-sleep-stop-your-code/